# I can't make my button delete a text created by an input in js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a web application to make to-do lists and delete them when they're done. I'm doing it with JavaScript. I made the input text go inside an "li" to an "ul" with a button next to it to be able to delete it once the task was completed. What i can't solve is how to program the buttons next to each task so that when they are pressed the task and its respective button are deleted. I hope someone can help me, here is the code:

```
const btnAgregar = document.getElementById('boton-agregar');   // id de un button
const tareaAgregar = document.getElementById('tarea');  // id de un input
const listaPendientes = document.getElementById('lista-pendientes'); // id de UL

btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', () =\>{
let li = document.createElement('li');
const texto = tareaAgregar.value;
li.innerText = texto;
listaPendientes.appendChild(li);
const btnDelete= document.createElement('button');
btnDelete.textContent="X";
btnDelete.className="btnDelete";
li.appendChild(btnDelete);
});

btnDelete.addEventListener('click', () =\>{
btnDelete.removeElement(li);
});
```

I tried this but it doesn't work and I still don't know much about javascript. I hoped that pressing the button would delete the li and the button too.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your example code is incomplete, please include the relevant HTML code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the problem in the end:

```js
const btnAgregar = document.getElementById('boton-agregar');   // id de un button
const tareaAgregar = document.getElementById('tarea');  // id de un input
const listaPendientes = document.getElementById('lista-pendientes'); // id de UL

function agregarItem(){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    const texto = tareaAgregar.value;
    li.innerText = texto;
    listaPendientes.appendChild(li);
    const btnDelete= document.createElement('button');
    btnDelete.textContent="X";
    btnDelete.className="btnDelete";
    btnDelete.addEventListener('click', () => deleteItem(li));
    li.appendChild(btnDelete);
    tareaAgregar.value = "";

}

function deleteItem(li) {
    
    li.remove()
    
}
btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', agregarItem);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lista de tareas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Lista de tareas</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
        <label for="tarea">Escriba la tarea pendiente</label>
        <input type="text" id="tarea" placeholder="tarea pendiente">
        <button id="boton-agregar">
            >
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id="lista-pendientes">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="botones.js">
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```